# How to use separate custom filters managed by Spring with multiple security configurations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, filter

I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days now and given my limited experience with Spring I've run out of ideas.

I have a simple Hello World Spring Boot app with security enabled. I need different security configs on different versions (`v1` and `v2`). Meaning that I need two different filters (extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) to be used by each of the configs. Filters also have to be managed by Spring so that env variables can be injected using `@Value`.

Security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class Config1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("******** Config1:config");
            http.antMatcher("/api/v1/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/greet").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public static class Config2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("******** Config2:config");
            http.antMatcher("/api/v2/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v2/greet").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }
}
```

Filters:

```
@Component
public class TestFilter1 extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    @Value("foo")
    private String foo;

    public TestFilter1(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
        System.out.println("************ TestFilter1:constructor");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("************ TestFilter1:doFilterInternal foo: " + this.foo);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Component
public class TestFilter2 extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    @Value("bar")
    private String bar;

    public TestFilter2(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
        System.out.println("************ TestFilter2:constructor");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("************ TestFilter2:doFilterInternal bar: " + this.bar);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/api/v1/greet")
    public String greet1() {
        System.out.println("************ GREETING V1");
        return "Hello Greeting 1";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/api/v2/greet")
    public String greet2() {
        System.out.println("************ GREETING V2");
        return "Hello Greeting 2";
    }
}
```

My problem is that even without any explicit assigment of the filter (e.g. `.addFilterBefore()`) they are both attached to both configs.

So hitting this:
`http://localhost:8010/api/v2/greet`
Prints this:

```
************ TestFilter1:doFilterInternal foo: foo
************ TestFilter2:doFilterInternal bar: bar
************ GREETING V1
```

While hitting other version:
`http://localhost:8010/api/v2/greet`
Prints this:

```
************ TestFilter1:doFilterInternal foo: foo
************ TestFilter2:doFilterInternal bar: bar
************ GREETING V2
```

As you can see in both cases both filters are called. In the initial setup i had them `@Autowired` as properties within `Config1/2` and attached using `.addFilterBefore()` but noticed that both filters are called regardless. More mysteriously removing `addFilterBefore()` they are still called.

So the question probably would be - How to make to make those filters not be attached automatically whilst still having them as Spring components?

Thanks in advance!